# Javascript not loading in blade bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Hello all I am building a new web app in the Laravel framework. I am new to Laravel & Blade and I have been stuck setting up my bootstrap template with blade.

It seems that when I yield a section into my main template file my javascript files do not run although I can see them on page inspection.

I also get the following error in my console;

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `enter code 
here`404 (Not Found) (script.js, line 0)
    [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
        ajax (jquery.min.js:6:13737)
        _evalUrl (jquery.min.js:6:142)
        domManip (jquery.min.js:5:28144)
        append (jquery.min.js:5:25583)
        (anonymous function) (custom.js:8)
        c (jquery.min.js:4:26057)
        fireWith (jquery.min.js:4:26858)
        ready (jquery.min.js:4:3317)
        q (jquery.min.js:4:723)
```

Here is my source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <!-- Seo Meta -->
        <meta name="description" content=" ">
        <meta name="keywords" content="iPress, magazine, light, dark, themeforest, multi purpose, premium, unlimited, blog, news, AD, optimized">

    <!-- Styles --><
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/icons.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/animate.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/responsive.css" media="screen" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EmulateIE8; IE=EDGE" />
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="layout" class="fluid">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="a_head">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="breaking_news lefter">
                        <div class="freq_out">
                            <div class="freq"><div class="inner_f"></div><div id="layerBall"></div></div>
                        </div><!-- /freq -->
                        <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Improving Search on the Envato Marketplaces: 2013 in Review</a></li>
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">4 Ways To Find Free and Unique Photos for Your Next Website Theme</a></li>
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Community Poll: Internet Speeds From Around the World in 2013</a></li>
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">New Hub, Header & Collections: 10 Ways to Improve Your Marketplaces Productivity</a></li>
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Get a Free Year of Tuts+ Premium by Trying New Relic</a></li>
                            <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Beyond Bland: 10+ Creative Packaging Designs That Will Leave You Inspired</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- /js news -->
                    </div><!-- /breaking news -->

                    <div class="right_bar">


                        <div class="social social_head">
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Twitter"><i class="fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Github"><i class="fa-github"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="instagram"><i class="fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="bottomtip" title="Dribbble"><i class="fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                        </div><!-- /social -->

                        <span id="date_time"></span><!-- /date -->
                    </div><!-- /right bar -->
                </div><!-- /row -->
            </div><!-- /a head -->

            <div class="b_head">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index-2.html" title="iPress - Responsive News/Blog/Magazine HTML5"><img src="images/logo/six-media-logo.png" alt="Six Media - The UK Media Powerhouse"></a>
                    </div><!-- /logo -->

                    <div class="ads">
                        <a href="#" title="ADS"><img src="images/ads.jpg" alt="ADS"></a>
                    </div><!-- /ads -->
                </div><!-- /row -->
            </div><!-- /b head -->

            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="sticky_true">
                    <div class="c_head clearfix">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="color5"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                                <li class="color2"><a href="category.html">Media</a>
                                    <ul class="col4 mega">
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Music Releases</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Rising Talent</a></li>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_2.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> Music Releases </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_3.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> What do you think about our website </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_4.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> Printer took a galley of type and scrambled </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="color3"><a href="category.html">News</a>
                                    <ul class="col4 mega">
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_1.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> Here's What Instagram Ads Will Look Like </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_2.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col1">
                                            <a href="single_post.html">
                                                <img src="images/assets/m_3.jpg" alt="#" title="#">
                                                <h4> What do you think about our website </h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="col1">
                                            <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Example 5</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="color5"><a href="category.html">Events</a></li>

                                <li class="color4"><a href="category.html">Services</a>
                                    <ul class="col4 mega">
                                        <div class="col1">
                                            <li><a href="#">Marketing & PR</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Production</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="color8"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- /menu -->
                        </nav><!-- /nav -->

                        <div class="right_icons">
                            <a class="random_post bottomtip" href="#" title="Random Post"><i class="icon-media-shuffle"></i></a><!-- /random post -->

                            <div class="search">
                                <div class="search_icon"><i class="fa-search"></i></div>
                                <div class="s_form">
                                    <form action="http://d.theme20.com/ipress/search_result.html" id="search" method="get">
                                        <input id="inputhead" name="search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value=='Start Searching...') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Start Searching...';" value="Start Searching..." placeholder="Start Searching ...">
                                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa-search"></i></button>
                                    </form><!-- /form -->
                                </div><!-- /s form -->
                            </div><!-- /search -->
                        </div><!-- /right icons -->
                    </div><!-- /c head -->
                </div><!-- /sticky -->
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </header><!-- /header -->

        <div class="page-content">

            @yield('home')

        </div>

<footer id="footer">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="grid_3">

                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title"><h4>About Six Media</h4></div>
                        <p> iPress is a magazine/blog/ad/review template. Nunc montes odio phasellus dignissim, aenean, nec augue velit integer elementum ut montes quis integer cursus, est purus, lectus duis, scelerisque tincidunt ultricies phasellus elementum turpis tristique.<br><br>

Email:  <a href="contact.html">info@sixmedia.co.uk</a> </p>
                    </div><!-- /widget -->
                </div><!-- /grid3 -->

                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title"><h4>Recent Posts</h4></div>
                        <ul class="small_posts">
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb4.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                <h3><a href="single_post.html">What is the worst could be the worst?</a></h3>
                                <div class="meta mb"> 1 day ago  /  <a href="single_post.html">1 comment</a> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb5.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                <div class="meta mb"> 3 days ago  /  <a href="single_post.html">3 comments</a> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb6.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                <h3><a href="single_post.html">Paul Thomson on post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
                                <div class="meta mb"> 6 days ago  /  <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /widget -->
                </div><!-- /grid3 -->

                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title"><h4>Newsletters</h4></div>
                        <p> To receive the latest updates and Latest Posts enter your email. </p>
                        <form id="newsletters" method="post" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=sevenpsd', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
                            <input type="email" onfocus="if (this.value=='Type Your Email') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Type Your Email';" value="Type Your Email" placeholder="Type Your Email" required="required">
                            <button type="submit"><i class="icon-checkmark"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- /widget -->
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title"><h4>Follow us</h4></div>
                        <div class="social">
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Twitter"><i class="fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Github"><i class="fa-github"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="instagram"><i class="fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="toptip" title="Dribbble"><i class="fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                        </div><!-- /social -->
                    </div><!-- /widget -->
                </div><!-- /grid3 -->

                <div class="grid_3">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title"><h4>Useful Links</h4></div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /widget -->
                </div><!-- /grid3 -->

            </div><!-- /row -->

            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="footer_last">
                    <span class="copyright">© 2018 <a href="#">Six Media</a>. All Rights Reserved.</span>

                    <div id="toTop" class="toptip" title="Back to Top"><i class="icon-arrow-thin-up"></i></div>
                </div><!-- /last footer -->
            </div><!-- /row -->

        </footer><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /layout -->

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <noscript>
  This page needs JavaScript activated to work.
</noscript>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ipress.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ticker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            function date_time(id){
                date = new Date;
                year = date.getFullYear();
                month = date.getMonth();
                months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
                d = date.getDate();
                day = date.getDay();
                days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
                h = date.getHours();
                if(h<10){
                    h = "0"+h;}
                    m = date.getMinutes();
                    if(m<10){
                        m = "0"+m;
                    }
                    s = date.getSeconds();
                    if(s<10){
                        s = "0"+s;
                    }
                // result = ''+days[day]+' '+months[month]+' '+d+' '+year+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s;
                result = ''+days[day]+' '+d+' '+months[month]+' '+year;
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;


setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
            return true;
        }
        window.onload = date_time('date_time');
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
```

---

Home view

```
@extends('layouts/main')


    @section('home')


    <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="grid_9 alpha">

                        <div class="ipress_slider mbf">
                            <div class="slider_a owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                <div class="item clearfix">
                                    <div class="half">
                                        <div class="slide_details">
                                            <a class="cat color3" href="#" title="View all posts under Entertainment">Entertainment</a>
                                            <span class="post_rating" href="#" title="Rating"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> 8.55</span>
                                            <h3><a href="single_post.html">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste</a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/slider1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div><!-- /half -->

                                    <div class="half">
                                        <div class="slide_details">
                                            <a class="cat color1" href="#" title="View all posts under People">People</a>
                                            <span class="post_rating" href="#" title="Rating"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> 9.1</span>
                                            <h3><a href="single_post.html">Discovered the undoubtable source</a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/slider2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div><!-- /half -->

                                    <div class="half">
                                        <div class="slide_details">
                                            <a class="cat color2" href="#" title="View all posts under Travel">Travel</a>
                                            <span class="post_rating" href="#" title="Rating"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> 7.42</span>
                                            <h3><a href="single_post.html">The standard chunk of Lorem ipsum</a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/slider3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div><!-- /half -->
                                </div><!-- /slide -->
                            </div><!-- /slider -->
                        </div><!-- /slider ipress -->
    <!-- HOME SLIDER END -->


                            <div class="grid_8 omega posts righter">
                                <div class="post_day mbf clearfix">                     
                                <div class="title colordefault"><h4>HOT TOPIC</h4></div>
    <!-- HOT TOPIC SECTION -->

                                <div class="grid_6 alpha relative">
                                    <a class="cat" href="#" title="View all posts under Travel">Travel</a>
                                    <a class="float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/r_4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div><!-- /grid6 alpha -->

                                <div class="grid_6 omega">
                                    <div class="post_day_content">
                                        <h3> <a href="single_post.html">Here's What Instagram Ads Will Look Like</a> </h3>
                                        <div class="meta mb"> 3 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">0 comments</a> </div>
                                        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type has survived not only fiv... </p>
                                    </div><!-- /post content -->

    <!-- HOT TOPIC SECTION -->
                                </div><!-- /grid6 omega -->
                            </div><!-- /post day -->

                            <div class="posts_block mbf clearfix">
                                <div class="title color5">
                                    <h4>IN THE MEDIA</h4>
                                    <a href="#" class="feed toptip" title="RSS Feed"><i class="icon-feed"></i></a>
                                </div><!-- /title bar -->

                                <div class="grid_6 alpha">
                                    <div class="mb float-shadow"><a href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/r_5.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                                    <div class="post_m_content">
                                        <h3> <a href="single_post.html">Here's What Instagram Ads Will Look Like</a> </h3>
                                        <div class="meta mb"> 3 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">0 comments</a> </div>
                                        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting... </p>
                                    </div><!-- post content -->
                                </div><!-- /grid6 omega -->

                                <div class="grid_6 omega">
                                    <div class="small_slider_music owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                        <div class="item clearfix">
                                            <ul class="small_posts">
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">What worst could be the worst?</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 5 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">1 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb2.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 1 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb3.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Paul Thomson on post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 3 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">14 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb4.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">For the days of peace and warmth</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 3 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">14 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item clearfix">
                                            <ul class="small_posts">
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb9.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">What worst could be the worst?</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 5 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">1 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb10.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 1 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /slides -->
                                </div><!-- grid6 omega -->
                            </div><!-- posts block Music -->

                            <div class="posts_block mbf clearfix">
                                <div class="title color6">
                                    <h4>FEATURED VIDEOS</h4>
                                    <a href="#" class="feed toptip" title="RSS Feed"><i class="icon-feed"></i></a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="carousel_TV">
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_7.jpg" alt="#" title="Lorem Ipsum is not simply"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_8.jpg" alt="#" title="Shooting for new goodies"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_9.jpg" alt="#" title="For the days of peace and warmth"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_10.jpg" alt="#" title="A picture of Sin Fang in Bairro Alto"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_11.jpg" alt="#" title="Breaking the darkness"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_12.jpg" alt="#" title="For the days of peace and warmth"></a></div>
                                    <div class="item float-shadow"><a href="#"><img class="toptip" src="images/assets/r_13.jpg" alt="#" title="Bairro Alto in Lisboa, Portugal"></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- posts block carousel -->

                            <div class="ads_block mbf">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/ads3.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div><!-- ads block -->

                            <div class="posts_block mbf clearfix">
                                <div class="title color1">
                                    <h4>SIX MEDIA NEWS</h4>
                                    <a href="#" class="feed toptip" title="RSS Feed"><i class="icon-feed"></i></a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid_6 alpha">
                                    <div class="mb float-shadow"><a href="single_post.html"><img src="images/assets/r_6.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                                    <div class="post_m_content">
                                        <h3> <a href="single_post.html">Here's What Instagram Ads Will Look Like</a> </h3>
                                        <div class="meta mb"> 3 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">0 comments</a> </div>
                                        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting... </p>
                                    </div><!-- post content -->
                                </div><!-- grid6 omega -->

                                <div class="grid_6 omega">
                                    <div class="small_slider_travel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                        <div class="item clearfix">
                                            <ul class="small_posts">
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb5.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">What worst could be the worst?</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 5 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">1 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb6.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 1 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb7.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Paul Thomson on post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 3 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">14 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb8.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">For the days of peace and warmth</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 3 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">14 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item clearfix">
                                            <ul class="small_posts">
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb11.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">What worst could be the worst?</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 5 hours ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">1 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb12.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 1 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="clearfix">
                                                    <a class="s_thumb float-shadow" href="single_post.html"><img width="70" height="70" src="images/assets/thumb6.jpg" alt="#"></a>
                                                    <h3><a href="single_post.html">Praesent ipsum adipiscing mi eget ipsum</a></h3>
                                                    <div class="meta mb"> 4 days ago    /    <a href="single_post.html">5 comments</a> </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- grid6 omega -->
                            </div><!-- posts block Travel -->



                        </div><!-- end grid9 -->

                        <div class="grid_4 alpha sidebar sidebar_b">
                            <div class="widget">

    <!-- LEFT SIDEBAR SECTION -->

                                <div class="title"><h4>NEW VIDEO</h4></div>
                                <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/13897659?color=E84A4A" height="180"></iframe><a href="http://vimeo.com/13897659">Iconic Poster design</a>
                            </div><!-- widget -->



                    </div><!-- /grid3 sidebar A -->
                </div><!-- /row -->
            </div>
    @stop
```

I am new to all of this so please forgive me if I am missing something

Appreciate any help

Thanks

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please change src attribute to your source code.

You should use Laravel`s build function to load css and js.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}">`